# Upload file in spring web mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, multipartform-data, spring-java-config

My Spring web application is based on java config, and contains web services.

All the other web requests work except for multipart requests. When I try to upload a file, it is giving me error,`the required string parameter Id is not present` but the request contains the parameter required.

I've added `multipart resolver` in the config. Here is the function to upload file

```
@PostMapping(path = "/upload")    
private String uploadImage(@RequestParam(name = "Id", required = true) String Id,
            @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile[] image) {

        return "Got it!!!";

}
```

and here is the multipart resolver bean

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver MultipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");

    return resolver;
}
```

I've tried adding `consumes="multipart/form-data"` in the request mapping.

Comment: Can you show the request headers?

Comment: Content-Type:multipart/form-data this is the header from postman which I use to send requests

Comment: No, *all* the headers.

Comment: I can see only the `Content-Type:multipart/form-data` in postman request header section

Comment: Did your file uploaded except that string or both doesn't work?

Comment: I removed the header from the postman, which was added manually by me and now it works, Thanks for your time